# django csrf cookie no longer working

Tags: django, django-csrf

I don't understand why, but Django has ceased including the csrf cookie in responses. I have the middleware enabled, have tried using RequestContext and am using render. I have even tried using the csrf_protect and requires_csrf_token decorators.

I am working on a dev server right now, and I can print the context after I use RequestContext, and it seems to include a csrf_token.

But when I look at the actual headers using Chrome's inspect element, the csrf_token isn't there, also when I use the console and type in "document.cookie" that does not have the csrf token.

HELP!

Here's an example view

```
@requires_csrf_token
def index(request):
    context = RequestContext(request, {'foo':'bar'})
    print context
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

The CSRF token seems to be in the context:

```
{u'csrf_token':         <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x1025ab990>}, ...
```

But it fails to make its way through...

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__utma=96992031.468590559.1369255550.1369255550.1369255550.1; __utmb=96992031.17.10.1369255550; __utmc=96992031; __utmz=96992031.1369255550.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
Host:127.0.0.1:8000
Referer:http://127.0.0.1:8000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.65 Safari/537.31
```

**UPDATE: Here is the template I'm using:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block hello %}
Basic Stock Event Charts
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}


  <div id="leftsidebar">
  <p>Use this tool to graph a time series data for a security. You can graph a security and
  four other features such as volume, call option volume, or implied volatility. The tool will 
  zoom in on the date of interest to show the target audience the changes in the selected
  vaiables preceeding the event. Because of large movement in variables before the announcement,
  it may be helpful to use the minimum and maximum tools to zoom in on smaller movements ahead
  of the event. </p>
    <div class="ui-widget inline">
        <label for="securities">1. Type in a ticker symbol</label>
        <input id="securities">
    </div>
    <div class="inline"><input type="button" id="reload" value="Reset" class="hide" /></div>

    <label for="datepicker">2. Pick your event date of interest.</label>
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" disabled />

    <label>3. Choose other series to graph.</label>
    <p><strong>Primary Axis</strong></p>
      Left Axis: <select id="series1" class="selectpicker span2" disabled><option value=""></option></select>
        <div id="series1minmax" class="hide">
            Min <input type="text" id="min1" class="input-mini" />&nbsp;
            Max <input type="text" id="max1" class="input-mini" />
        </div><input type="button" id="addaxes1" value="Graph" class="hide" />
        <input type="button" id="removeaxes1" value="Remove" class="hide" /><br />

      <br/>Right Axis: <select id="series2" class="selectpicker span2" disabled><option value=""></option>></select>
        <div id="series2minmax" class="hide">
            Min <input type="text" id="min2" class="input-mini" />&nbsp;
            Max <input type="text" id="max2" class="input-mini" />
        </div><input type="button" id="addaxes2" value="Graph" class="hide" />
        <input type="button" id="removeaxes2" value="Remove" class="hide" /><br />

        <input type="button" id="addextraaxis" value="Add Additional Axis" disabled/><br />

      <div id="additional" class="hide">
      <p><strong>Additional Axis</strong></p>
      Left Axis: <select id="series3" class="selectpicker span2" disabled><option value=""></option></select>
        <div id="series3minmax" class="hide">
            Min <input type="text" id="min3" class="input-mini" />&nbsp;
            Max <input type="text" id="max3" class="input-mini" />
        </div><input type="button" id="addaxes3" value="Graph" class="hide" />
        <input type="button" id="removeaxes3" value="Remove" class="hide" /><br />

      <br/>Right Axis: <select id="series4" class="selectpicker span2" disabled><option value=""></option>></select>
        <div id="series4minmax" class="hide">
            Min <input type="text" id="min4" class="input-mini" />&nbsp;
            Max <input type="text" id="max4" class="input-mini" />
        </div><input type="button" id="addaxes4" value="Graph" class="hide" />
        <input type="button" id="removeaxes4" value="Remove" class="hide" /><br />
      </div>

  </div>
  <div id="rightsidebar">
    <div id="container" class="hide"></div>
    </div>
  </div>


<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highcharts-more.js"></script>

<script>

$(function() {
  $("#removefromchart").click(function() {
      var conceptName = $('#savedseries').find(":selected").remove();
  });

  $("#reload").click(function() {
      location.reload();
  })

  $("#addextraaxis").click(function() {
      $("#additional").removeClass("hide");
      this.disabled = true
      $("#addextraaxis").addClass("hide");
      var chart = $("#container").highcharts();
      chart.setSize(null, 650);
  })
});

$(function() {
        $("#series1").change(function() {   
            $("#addaxes1").removeClass("hide");
        });
        $("#series2").change(function() {
            $("#addaxes2").removeClass("hide");
        });
        $("#series3").change(function() {
            $("#addaxes3").removeClass("hide");
        });
        $("#series4").change(function() {
            $("#addaxes4").removeClass("hide");
        });
});


$(function() {
    function setExtreme(isMin, axis, value) {
        console.log("fired");
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        if (isMin) { 
            console.log(value + " " + chart.yAxis[axis].getExtremes()["max"])
            chart.yAxis[axis].setExtremes(value, chart.yAxis[axis].getExtremes()["max"]);
        } else {
            console.log(value + " " + chart.yAxis[axis].getExtremes()["min"])
            chart.yAxis[axis].setExtremes(chart.yAxis[axis].getExtremes()["min"], value);
        }
        console.log(value);
    }


    function getAxisNumber(series) {
        var indicies = {}
        $.each(chart.yAxis, function(index, element) {
            indicies[element.options.id] = index;
            console.log(element.options.id);
        });
        return indicies[series]
    }

    $("#max1").change(function() {setExtreme(0, getAxisNumber("#series1"), this.value)});
    $("#min1").change(function() {setExtreme(1, getAxisNumber("#series1"), this.value)});
    $("#max2").change(function() {setExtreme(0, getAxisNumber("#series2"), this.value)});
    $("#min2").change(function() {setExtreme(1, getAxisNumber("#series2"), this.value)});
    $("#max3").change(function() {setExtreme(0, getAxisNumber("#series3"), this.value)});
    $("#min3").change(function() {setExtreme(1, getAxisNumber("#series3"), this.value)});
    $("#max4").change(function() {setExtreme(0, getAxisNumber("#series4"), this.value)});
    $("#min4").change(function() {setExtreme(1, getAxisNumber("#series4"), this.value)});

});

$(function()
        {
          $("#removefromchart").click(function()
          {
              var conceptName = $('#savedseries').find(":selected").remove();
          });
        });

$(function() {

    function addPlotLine(ts) {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotBand({
            from: ts,
            to: ((ts + 86400000) * 365),
            color: 'rgba(68, 170, 213, 0.2)',
            id: 'tsband'
        });
        chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
            value: ts,
            color: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',
            width: 1,
            id: 'tsline'
        });
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(ts - (86400000 * 30), ts + 86400000)
        }

    function removeEventIfExists() {
        var chart = $("#container").highcharts()
        chart.xAxis[0].removePlotBand("tsband");
        chart.xAxis[0].removePlotLine("tsline");
    }

    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,  /*added by oussama*/
        changeMonth: true, /*added by oussama*/
        changeYear: true, /*added by oussama*/
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            utcDate = Date.UTC(dateText.split("-")[0], dateText.split("-")[1] - 1, dateText.split("-")[2]);
            removeEventIfExists();
            addPlotLine(utcDate);
            $("#series1").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#series2").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#series3").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#series4").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("#addextraaxis").removeAttr("disabled");
            var ticker = $("#securities").val();
            var date = $("#datepicker").val();
            chart.setTitle({text: ticker + " around " + date});
        }
    });


  });

$(function() {

    function createChart() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        var options = {chart: { 
                           renderTo: 'container',
                           height: 450,
                       },
                       events: {
                           load: function(event) {
                               this.setExtremes();
                           }
                       },
                       rangeSelector: {
                         enabled: false,
                       },
                       exporting: {
                           enabled: false,
                       },
                       navigator: {
                             enabled: true,
                             series: { id: 'navigator' },
                       },
                        yAxis: [{
                            title: {
                                text: 'Price'
                            },
                            height: 150,
                        }],


            },

        chart = new Highcharts.StockChart(options);
        return chart;
    }

  $("#securities").autocomplete({
    source: "/api/get_securities/",
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var ticker = ui.item.label;
        getSeries(ticker);
        chart = createChart();
        getTimeSeriesData(ticker + "|PX_LAST", 0);
        $('#container').show();
        $('#datepicker').removeAttr("disabled");
        $('#reload').removeClass("hide");
        chart.setTitle({text: ticker});
        this.disabled = 'disabled';
    },
  });
});

$(function() {

    function removeAxes(id) {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        chart.get(id).remove();
    }

    $("#removeaxes1").click(function() {
        console.log("removeaxes1 clicked");
        removeAxes("#series1");
        $("#removeaxes1").addClass("hide");
        $("#series1minmax").addClass("hide");
        $("#series1minmax").removeClass("inline");
        $("#series1").val("");
        $("#min1").val("");
        $("#max1").val("");
        $("#series1").removeAttr("disabled");
    });

    $("#removeaxes2").click(function() {
        console.log("removeaxes2 clicked");
        removeAxes("#series2");
        $("#removeaxes2").addClass("hide");
        $("#series2minmax").addClass("hide");
        $("#series2minmax").removeClass("inline");
        $("#series2").val("");
        $("#min2").val("");
        $("#max2").val("");
        $("#series2").removeAttr("disabled");
    });

    $("#removeaxes3").click(function() {
        console.log("removeaxes3 clicked");
        removeAxes("#series3");
        $("#removeaxes3").addClass("hide");
        $("#series3minmax").addClass("hide");
        $("#series3minmax").removeClass("inline");
        $("#series3").val("");
        $("#min3").val("");
        $("#max3").val("");
        $("#series3").removeAttr("disabled");
    });

    $("#removeaxes4").click(function() {
        console.log("removeaxes4 clicked");
        removeAxes("#series4");
        $("#removeaxes4").addClass("hide");
        $("#series4minmax").addClass("hide");
        $("#series4minmax").removeClass("inline");
        $("#series4").val("");
        $("#min4").val("");
        $("#max4").val("");
        $("#series4").removeAttr("disabled");
    });

    function addSeries(id, minMaxId, isOpposite, isAdditional) {

        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        indicies = {}
        console.log('climlckedaddaxes');
        var series = $(id).val()
        var top = 210
        if (isAdditional) top = 380
        var options = {
            title: {
                text: series.split("|")[1]
            },
            top: top,
            height: 150,
            opposite: isOpposite,
            id: id,
            offset: -30
        }
        chart.addAxis(options)
        $.each(chart.yAxis, function(index, element) {
            indicies[element.options.id] = index;
            console.log(element.options.id);
        });
        getTimeSeriesData(series, indicies[id]);
        $(minMaxId).removeClass("hide")
        $(minMaxId).addClass("inline")
    }

    $("#addaxes1").click(function() {   
        addSeries('#series1', "#series1minmax", false, false);  
        $("#addaxes1").addClass("hide")
        $("#removeaxes1").removeClass("hide")
        $("#series1").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    });

    $("#addaxes2").click(function() {           
        addSeries('#series2', "#series2minmax", true, false);
        $("#addaxes2").addClass("hide")
        $("#removeaxes2").removeClass("hide")
        $("#series2").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    });

    $("#addaxes3").click(function() {           
        addSeries('#series3', "#series3minmax", false, true);
        $("#addaxes3").addClass("hide")
        $("#removeaxes3").removeClass("hide")
        $("#series3").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    });

    $("#addaxes4").click(function() {           
        addSeries('#series4', "#series4minmax", true, true);
        $("#addaxes4").addClass("hide")
        $("#removeaxes4").removeClass("hide")
        $("#series4").attr("disabled", "disabled")
    });

})

$('#addtochart').click(function() {
  var selectedValues = $('#seriesselector').val();
  $.each(selectedValues, function(index, value) {
        $('#savedseries').append($('<option>', {
                                                value: value,
                                                text: value,
                                                selected: true,
                                                }));
        $('#seriesselector option[value="' + value +'"]').remove();
  });
});

function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
        var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}

function parseDate(inputdate, value) {
    var date = inputdate;
    var year = parseInt(date.split("-")[0]);
    var month = parseInt(date.split("-")[1]) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(date.split("-")[2]);
    var outputdate = Date.UTC(year, month, day);
    if (year == 2013 && month == 3) {
        //console.log(inputdate, outputdate, value);
    }
    return outputdate;
};

function getTimeSeriesData(seriesName, axis) {
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
console.log('csrftoken is :: ' + csrftoken);
  $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                },
                data: {'seriesName': seriesName }, // get the form data
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/api/get_time_series_data/',
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    console.log(response);
                    var series = {}
                    series['name'] = response[0]['series_name'];
                    series['data'] = []
                    $.each(response, function(index, value) {
                        series['data'][index] = [
                            parseDate(response[index]['date'], response[index]['value']), 
                            parseFloat(response[index]['value'])
                            ];
                    });
                   series['yAxis'] = axis
                   series['marker'] = {
                           enabled : true,
                           radius : 3
                           }
                   var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
                   chart.addSeries(series);
                   var nav = chart.get('navigator');
                   if (axis == 0) nav.setData(series['data']);          
                }
            });
            return false;
};

function getSeries(ticker) {
var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');  
  $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...
                beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
                    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                },
                data: {'ticker': ticker }, // get the form data
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/api/get_series/',
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    $('#seriesselector').empty()
                    for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                        if (response[i].value == 'PX_LAST') continue;
                        $('#series1').append($('<option>', {
                                value: ticker + "|" + response[i].value,
                                text: response[i].value
                        }));
                        $('#series2').append($('<option>', {
                            value: ticker + "|" + response[i].value,
                            text: response[i].value
                        }));
                        $('#series3').append($('<option>', {
                            value: ticker + "|" + response[i].value,
                            text: response[i].value
                        }));
                        $('#series4').append($('<option>', {
                            value: ticker + "|" + response[i].value,
                            text: response[i].value
                        }));
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
};

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you post the template you are using?

Comment: Posted. funny thing this was working before, not sure what changed.

Comment: Did beforeSend get called? Also consider clearing your cache. Some times working on multiple projects can mess up your site variables.

Comment: Another option is to run in incognito mode if you are using chrome.

Comment: yes beforesend gets called. when i type document.cookie it says null, it used to contain the csrf cookie.

Comment: Can you post relavent part of the settings.py. TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS and MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, INTALLED_APPS? Just doubling checking the obvious in case you have been staring at the problem too long.

Comment: pass {% csrf_token %} as a data element in the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out you need the

```
{% csrf_token %}
```

regardless of whether or not you are posting a html form. I was only doing AJAX requests, but Django won't include the token in the response header unless it sees it the template.

Comment: This is only appropriate if rendering a template.  Many views, especially for Rest, do not.